# cannot render images properly using ejs.renderfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to create a pdf from rendered ejs file but cannot render image properly no matter how I try.

my app.js :

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let ejs = require("ejs");
let pdf = require("html-pdf");
let path = require("path");

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );

app.get("/generateReport", (req, res) => {
    ejs.renderFile("./views/report-template.ejs",  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
          res.send(err);
    } else {

        pdf.create(data).toFile("certificate.pdf", function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.send("File created successfully");
            }
        });
    }
});
})
app.listen(3000, function(){ 
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
  }); 


----------
```

my report-template.ejs file

```
<html>
    <body>
       <img src="certificate.jpg" width=675   height=792>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I've saved certificated.jpg in all the locations including root,public etc..but it does'nt work..Please help ..I'm new to coding and node.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me, parameter "base" in options pdf 
//base: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`

```
var options = {
                        "format": "A4",
                        "orientation": "portrait",
                         base: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`,
               };

pdf.create(resulthtml, options).toStream(function(err, stream) {
                        if (err) res.end('An error occurred on create pdf');
                        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' + stream.filename + '"');
                        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
                        stream.pipe(res);
});
```

then now in template

```
<img src="/public/image.png">
```

or simply

```
 <img src="image.png">
```

Comment: I used the file protocol in base.